# insert row in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

In the below response I need to get validation rules array. I need to display field names from validationRules in another viewcontroller's tableview.

```
(
{
    accountPurpose = 4;
    accountType = Savings;
    bankUserId = Jjhhhhj;
    bankerCode = "BASSEIN CATHOLIC CO-OP BANK (Band)";
    createdTimeStamp = "<null>";
    creditCardExpiry = "<null>";
    creditCardNumber = "<null>";
    customerAccountType =         (
                    {
            description = "<null>";
            id = 0;
            name = "<null>";
        }
    );
    debitCardExpiry = "<null>";
    debitCardNumber = "<null>";
    defaultAccount = 0;
    enabled = true;
    id = 940;
    mmid = 2323223;
    phoneNumber = 9177509924;
    serverId = 940;
    updatedTimeStamp = "<null>";
    validationRules =         (
                    {
            fieldDataType = String;
            fieldDisplayName = MPIN;
            fieldName = mpin;
            fieldStatus = No;
            id = 58;
            maxFieldLength = 6;
            minFieldLength = 4;
        }
    );
}

)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please put the code that you have try.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get your required string for the cell's textfield. Create a global array to store validation rules like `validationRulesArray` which I used here. After getting your JSON, extract validationRules array as follows

```
let aDictionary = resultArray!.firstItem as! NSDictionary
self.validationRulesArray = aDictionary.objectForKey("validationRules") as! NSArray
```

You can pass this `validationRulesArray` to another view for displaying. In your `cellForIndexPath` delegate method, write the following to get the string.

```
let validationDictionary = self.validationRulesArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary    
cell.textLabel.text = validationDictionary.objectForKey("fieldName") as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Phillipus/JSONHandler   Just go to the link and download the project i think this is perfect solution for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

After response of your webservice you will get array of dictionary of all key data.

```
let validationRulesArray =  NSMutableArray()
```

So in response of webservice..

```
for resultDictionary in resultArray{
     validationRulesArray.addObject(resultDictionary.objectForKey("validationRules") as NSDictionary)
}
```

And you can pass this array to another view controller..And use that array data to display in tableview..